# HTA in WinPE - Button OnClick event not working

Tags: vbscript, hta, winpe

I have a very simple HTA code that produces a menu while running under WinPE 5.1, basically it is simply 5 buttons on the screen, each button should call a CMD file, however nothing happens.

```
    <head>
<title>Recovery</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
     APPLICATIONNAME="Recovery"
     SCROLL="no"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
     WINDOWSTATE="maximize"
     maximizeButton="no"
     minimizeButton="no"
     icon="HTA\sbicon.ico"

>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">

    'Sub Window_onLoad
        'window.resizeTo 400,250
    'End Sub        

    Sub Createimage
       Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
       WshShell.Run "x:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c START /MIN image.cmd", 1 ,TRUE
    End Sub
   </script>

   <script language="VBScript">
    Sub RecoverPart
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
       WshShell.Run "x:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c START /MIN part.cmd", 1 ,True
    End Sub
   </script>

   <script language="VBScript">
    Sub RecoverUSB
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
       WshShell.Run "x:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c START /MIN usb.cmd", 1 ,TRUE
    End Sub
   </script>

   <script language="VBScript">
    Sub Reboot
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
       WshShell.Run "X:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c START /MIN restart.cmd", 1 ,TRUE
    End Sub
   </script>

   <script language="VBScript">
    Sub Shutdown
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
       WshShell.Run "x:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c START /MIN shutdwn.cmd", 1 ,TRUE
    End Sub

</script>

<body bgcolor="#003E67">

    <center><img src="HTA\Smartbox2.jpg"/>

    <br><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Create Image" name="run_button"  onClick="Createimage" style="Width: 300px; height: 75px; font-family: roboto; font-size: 25px;"><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Recover From Partition" name="run_button"  onClick="RecoverPart" style="Width: 300px; height: 75px; font-family: roboto; font-size: 25px;"><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Recover From USB" name="run_button"  onClick="RecoverUSB" style="Width: 300px; height: 75px; font-family: roboto; font-size: 25px;"><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Restart Device" name="run_button"  onClick="Reboot" style="Width: 300px; height: 75px; font-family: roboto; font-size: 25px;"><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Shutdown Device" name="run_button"  onClick="Shutdown" style="Width: 300px; height: 75px; font-family: roboto; font-size: 25px;"><br><br></Center>
</body>
```

Any help would be appreciated in making the CMD run.

Regards

C.

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me.  I had to change X to C for it to launch CMD though.  I changed mine to `WshShell.Run "%systemroot%\system32\cmd.exe`

Minor things: you're missing beginning and ending `<html>` (which might be the code editor here doing that) and I would also put the end head after all the scripts.  I would also suggest a `Set WshShell = Nothing` at the end of each Sub.  Also not sure why you created a script section around each Sub instead of one big one but it doesn't hurt anything I know of.

```
<html>
<head>    
<HTA:APPLICATION 
    APPLICATIONNAME="Recovery"
    SCROLL="no"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
    WINDOWSTATE="maximize"
    maximizeButton="no"
    minimizeButton="no"
    icon="HTA\sbicon.ico"
    >
<title>Recovery</title>
<script>
...
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Also, if you'd like to not link to external jpg, you can base64 encode them and put them in there like this:
`<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,`  put your encoded text in and finish `">`